# Azure data factory - query pipeline by data annotations

Tags: data-annotations, azure-data-factory

Is there a way to programmatically query (using .net SDK) list of running pipelines by data annotations?

I can set data annotation when I run pipeline as explained [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/azure-friday-enhanced-monitoring-capabilities-and-tagsannotations-in-azure-data-factory/), but not sure how to query pipelines or filter pipelines using the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.models.runqueryfilter?view=azure-dotnet), query pipelines by annotation is not supported. Filter parameter support following:

> Gets or sets parameter name to be used for filter. The allowed
> operands to query pipeline runs are PipelineName, RunStart, RunEnd and
> Status; to query activity runs are ActivityName, ActivityRunStart,
> ActivityRunEnd, ActivityType and Status, and to query trigger runs are
> TriggerName, TriggerRunTimestamp and Status. Possible values include:
> 'PipelineName', 'Status', 'RunStart', 'RunEnd', 'ActivityName',
> 'ActivityRunStart', 'ActivityRunEnd', 'ActivityType', 'TriggerName',
> 'TriggerRunTimestamp', 'RunGroupId', 'LatestOnly'